# Expecting an Object which implements from class A and from interface B - Any option/pattern to force that?

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios

**Situation:**

I'm using Monotouch for iOS development (C#) and one of the main classes is UIViewController.
There are a lot of existing classes in the iOS library (or third party) which implements from that and there are also a lot of function calls returning an UIViewController object.

I now created an abstract function which should be implemented in subclasses and **it has to return a "UIViewController with a PageNumber parameter"**.

I have following abstract method (my method):

```
public abstract PageViewController GetPageViewController(int pageNumber);
```

With:

```
public class PageViewController: UIViewController{

        public int PageNumber = 0;
            ...
```

So I'm getting a UIViewController which has a "PageNumber" parameter (exactly what I needed).
When creating a UIViewController, I derive from "PageViewController" instead of "UIViewController".

**My problem:**

iOS has a lot of subclasses deriving from UIViewController.
For example, UICollectionViewController.

If I want to use a "UICollectionViewController", I can not derive from "PageViewController" because it doesn't have the additional functionality implemented in "UICollectionViewController".

The only way would be to change "PageViewController" to

```
public class PageViewController: UICollectionViewController{
```

However, if I need to pass another subclass of UIViewController, I'm stuck again.

Creating an object holding two parameters (an UIViewController & a PageNumber) is also not possible, because the UIViewController will be used by iOS and I need to be able to retrieve the pagenumber when I get the UIViewController object back at a later point from iOS.

The only way to have "something" with my current knowledge is:

1) Change

```
public abstract PageViewController GetPageViewController(int pageNumber);
```

to

```
public abstract UIViewController GetPageViewController(int pageNumber);
```

This will make sure that you can pass "any" UIViewController(including all subclasses)

2)
Define an interface with parameter PageNumber (IPageNumber for example)

3) 
Document that you should pass a UIViewController which also implements this additional interface

4) 
When the UIViewController is returned at a certain point, check if it is also a "IPageNumber". If not, throw an error.

Off course, this will throw an error at runtime and not at compile time.

Does anyone know if there is a better solution for this problem?

PS: I'm an inexperienced hobby developer, so apologies if some of my terminology is incorrect. I also searched but couldn't find anything (also because I don't know good keywords to search on)

Comment: It is really hard to understand what exactly you want from your wall of text. Please condense it with what you want, what you have tried, what failed, in as few words as possible. More code, less rambling text.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use Interfaces instead? Like:

```
public interface IPageViewController
{
    int PageNumber { get; }
}
```

Make your `UIViewController` or `UICollectionViewController` implement it:

```
public class PageViewController: UIViewController, IPageViewController
{
    public int PageNumber { get; private set; }
    ...
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I had, but in this case I'm stuck when I would like to use a UICollectionViewController. In that case I would need to implement for example  "PageCollectionViewController : UICollectionViewController, IPageViewController". But then I have for every subclass of UIViewController a corresponding "xxPageXX" class + I can only define one returning type for my abstract function, so not "PageViewController" and "PageCollectionViewController"

Comment: Why cant you define the return type to `IPageViewController`?

Comment: Because in that case, a person who suclasses my abstract class can create a random class implementing IPageViewController without being a UIViewController. So basically I'm expecting any "UIViewController" (including all subclasses) but with an additional PageNumber object. Do you understand what I mean or still not?

Comment: That is his problem, not yours.

Comment: I still am not sure what you want to achieve by having a `PageNumber` in your ViewControllers. What is the purpose. Is it possible you could have something else tracking this number?

Comment: It is true that it is the problem of the caller :-) But everyone could also use "Object" as return type and leave it up to the caller to use the correct type. So I was wondering if there is any way to notify this at compile time, because C# allows you to derive from a normal/abstract class and from an interface

Comment: UIPageViewController allows you to set Functions for retrieving the previous and next UIViewController with "PageViewController.GetNextViewController = GetNextPageViewController;" and "PageViewController.GetPreviousViewController = GetPreviousPageViewController;" (this is defined by iOS, I have no control over that). These functions will be called by "UIPageViewController" and it will pass the current UIViewController as a parameter. I need to retrieve the page of that UIViewController. So that's why I'm storing it

Comment: Maybe using CollectionView is a better solution for you. But also look at this sample: https://github.com/xamarin/monotouch-samples/tree/a98c0b6caa3839d97c2671a21a6ff9115f2c2f65/FrogScroller/FrogScroller

Comment: He's doing the same as me, storing the "PageNumber" in the "ImageViewController" which derives from UIViewController. In the "GetPreviousViewController" method, he's retrieving the pagenumber by casting first. However, what if you're using different subclasses of UIViewController instead of only a "ImageViewController"? You can solve that by casting to an interface like "IPageViewController" instead, but because "ImageViewControllerForPageIndex" has to return a UIViewController, you can't force that the returned type really implemented IPageViewController or throw an error at compile time.

Comment: There is no reason you couldn't store the page numbers and their instances in the `UIPageViewControllerDataSource`. But do what you find suits you best and gets the job done.

Comment: Storing them would defeat the recycling implementation of the pagecontroller. I have something working, so i'm not stuck. I just wanted to know how other people are solving this issue on a proper way or if there is no generic way of solving this problem.